# Selectize with Ajax call autocomplete and Elastic search on Laravel

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, laravel-5, autocomplete, selectize.js

i try to make a Facebook Style User search using elastiquent on Laravel 5.5 that autocomplete ad sugest user by typing some char in input field.
The response from Ajax call return correct object but in my js code there is probably somethings wrong.
This the elasticsearch url http://basketmapp.com/users-list?q=Paolo, and in response i can see that item is correctly fetched:

[image]

this is the js used for selectize:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var topUserSearch = $('.js-user-search');

    if (topUserSearch.length) {
        topUserSearch.selectize({
            persist: false,
            maxItems: 2,
            valueField: 'name',
            labelField: 'name',
            searchField: ['name'],
            options: [],
            render: {
                option: function(item, escape) {
                    return '<div class="inline-items">' +
                        (item.avatar ? '<div class="author-thumb"><img src="' + escape(item.avatar) + '" alt="avatar"></div>' : '') +
                        '<div class="notification-event">' +
                        (item.first_name ? '<span class="h6 notification-friend"></a>' + escape(item.first_name) + '</span>' : '') +
                        '</div>';
                },
                item: function(item, escape) {
                    var label = item.first_name;
                    return '<div>' +
                        '<span class="label">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
            },
            load: function(query, callback) 
            {
                if (!query.length) return callback();
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: '/users-list',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 
                    {
                        q: query
                    },
                    error: function() 
                    {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function(res) 
                    {
                        callback(res.data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

need your help!

Comment: in my js code there is probably somethings wrong. what is wrong ?? what do you want to add ?

Comment: The html render not work. I didn't see any result in box